# Issue with Sharepoint DateTimeControl

Tags: visual-web-part, date-time

DateTimeControl is inside grid and I bind the grid inside !ispostback section, on row databound of grid I find that datetimecontrol and disable it.

When button click event (outside of grid), the DateTimeControl gets enabled.

There is no code inside button click event.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: And you haven't written any code on Button_Click event?

Comment: no i hadn't written any code on Button_Click.

Comment: DateTimeControl is inside grid and i bind grid inside !ispostback section, on row databound of grid i find that datetimecontrol and disabled it.

Comment: I think it would be easier if you just show us your problematic code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific to what you want to achieve. Instead of you binding dateTime control at !ispostback section why don't you try adding a date and time column to SharePoint list.

If you are using the data from external sources such as sql then you should consider using external list in BDC which is for same purpose i.e. binding a Sharepoint list from external datasource .

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding below code in databound event

```
DateTimeControl dtc = new DateTimeControl();

((TextBox)dtc.Controls[0]).ReadOnly = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can disable it in two ways.

The first one is code behind how @Manish shows to you (I don't know if it works).
The 2nd way is using JavaScript in combo with JQuery:

1 - Select the element base on its id

2 - Then disable the textbox and the button on the DateTime control (if you provide the rendered HTML I can write to you the required JQuery code)